# Adding the sections in the header in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, presentations, powerdot

Good evening to everyone. I have a very simple question, that for sure has been asked and answered  either here or in some guide. The problem is, with the keywords I used, I couldn't find the answer by myself, and every guide I found doesn't mention the problem:

In a nutshell, how do I add the sections in the header of each slide?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `miniframes` outer theme seems to be what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}

\section{second section}
\begin{frame}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I don't get why no guide talks about outer themes...